# Non-negative compactly supported function with zero divergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm looking for a function $f : [0,T] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $$ \partial_{t}f + \partial_{x}f = 0$$ on $[0,T] \times \mathbb{R}$ with the following requirements:

1. $f$ has compact support in space: for any fixed $t \in [0,T]$ we have $\text{supp}(f(t,\cdot)) \subseteq [t, 1+t]$
2. $f  \ge 0$.

The derivatives can be understood in the weak sense.

I am not sure how to construct such an example, or if one even exists. My first thought goes to bump functions, or a 'triangle' function. But my issue with these attempts is that I couldn't find ones which satisfy $\partial_{t}f + \partial_{x}f = 0 $ unfortunately.

Comment: Fixing a deleted typo, this is a transport equation, not a zero divergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution to $\partial_{t}f + \partial_{x}f = 0$ with the initial condition $f(0,x)=f_0(x)$ is $f(t,x)=f_0(x-t)$, i.e., the initial profile moves to the right with unity velocity without deformation. Therefore, if you choose $f_0$ such that $\text{supp}(f_0(\cdot)) \subseteq [0, 1]$ and $f_0(x)\geq 0$, then $\text{supp}(f(t,\cdot)) \subseteq [t, t+1]$ and $f(t,x)\geq 0$.